# How to do Copy and Transform techniques in Eventstore?

Tags: migration, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I am trying to modified the event type name in eventstore because of the domains need changed.So I have to migrate the eventstore. I researched some topics about how to do it. Since the events are immutable its hard to change the event type name. There are some ways to change it. One way is that Copy and Transform events techniques. When I read the articles they said read the all events from old eventstore then modified the events after write all events to the new eventstore. It's good and it will fix my solution. But I couldn't find any tiny example about how to do that. So I confused. I find one way but it's work only postgresql but I'm using eventstore for storing the data.

I will be very happy if someone showed me ways that he I can do Copy and Transform techniques.

Thank you to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Gerg wrote a whole book about event versioning and you can read it for free: https://leanpub.com/esversioning/read

I'm not an expert but just read from the stream with a subscription, make the change and write to another stream with another name-version, there's no much more than that I guess.

Some examples about subscriptions using the C# client: https://github.com/edgarjrg/eventstore-resource-collection#c

I found myself with the same lack of learning material so I created that repo, feel free to contribute to it.